# QSplitter more than two items

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar, qsplitter

I would like to create a QSplitter with 5 items in it

```
<div class="q-px-md">
      <Buttons/>
      <Buttons/>
      <Buttons/>
      <Buttons/>
      <Buttons/>
</div>
```

As I run through the documentation, I can not find a way to implement it with these 5 items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could embed `QSplitter` into another `QSplitter` like this:

```
   <q-splitter v-model="splitterModel" style="height: 400px">
     <template v-slot:before>
       <q-splitter v-model="splitterModel" style="height: 400px">

         <template v-slot:before>
           <q-btn color="white" text-color="black" label="Standard" />
         </template>

         <template v-slot:after>
           <q-splitter v-model="splitterModel" style="height: 400px">

             <template v-slot:before>
               <q-btn color="primary" label="Primary" />
             </template>

             <template v-slot:after>
               <q-btn color="secondary" label="Secondary" />
             </template>

           </q-splitter>
         </template>

       </q-splitter>
     </template>

     <template v-slot:after>
       <q-splitter v-model="splitterModel" style="height: 400px">

         <template v-slot:before>
           <q-btn color="amber" glossy label="Amber" />
         </template>

         <template v-slot:after>
           <q-btn color="brown-5" label="Brown 5" />
         </template>

       </q-splitter>
     </template>

   </q-splitter>
```

For your reference:

- [Documentation](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/splitter#embedded)
- Codepen: https://codepen.io/hoangdng-the-sans/pen/WNJBNBY

Answer (score 0):

Your `v-model` variables should map to two different variables. That way, splitting one way does not affect the other split.

For example, `v-model="splitterModel1"` and `v-model="splitterModel2"`.